# Can I use Secret Invasion to transfer a trap card in front of me to another player?

Tags: munchkin

In a game of [Munchkin: Marvel Edition](https://munchkin.game/products/games/munchkin-marvel/), a trap is played on me that says I get -5 in my next combat, an additional -5 at night and an additional -5 if it’s raining for a whooping -15 to my next combat. The card explicitly states to "keep this card in front of you as a reminder."

I have in my hand the Secret Invasion trap card that says "immediately exchange all cards *in front of you* with the person on your right." Can I play Secret Invasion on the person on my left and give them the trap?

Comment: Hi, Austin Murray, and welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange. I've tried to copyedit your question a little, but I'm not 100% sure that I got it right, so could you please check that I didn't introduce any mistakes by accident? (In particular, I don't own Munchkin: Marvel Edition myself, so I had to guess which trap you meant.) If I did, or if you feel there's something else to improve, please feel free to [edit] your question yourself and fix it (or even revert it all back to the way it was before, if you feel that's best). Thanks, and I hope you'll get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

### No, you can't.

The trap is being kept in front of you as a *reminder*.  The effect has already been applied.

Arguably you could say that the reminder card moves, the the minus effect won't move with it.

Notice that the trap has no rules about discarding itself.  As currently worded, if it was applying the effect it would stay in front of you forever, giving you -15 until you found a way to discard it with a different card.  This doesn't happen because the card isn't officially in play - it's just a memory tool that you can discard freely once it's done with its purpose.